# SocketException was caught

Tags: c#, networking

My code

This code for server

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly byte[] Localhost = {127,0,0,1};
        private const int Port = 8567;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var address = new IPAddress( Localhost );
            var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, Port);

            var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(endPoint);// Error in this line 
                listener.Listen(3);

                String data = "";

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Listening on sport {0}", endPoint);


                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                    // handle incoming connection ...
                    var handler = listener.Accept();
                    Console.WriteLine("Handling incoming connection ...");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int count = handler.Receive(buffer);
                        data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

                        // Find start of MLLP frame, a VT character ...
                        int start = data.IndexOf((char) 0x0B);
                        if (start >= 0)
                        {
                            // Now look for the end of the frame, a FS character
                            int end = data.IndexOf((char) 0x1C);
                            if (end > start)
                            {
                                string temp = data.Substring(start + 1, end - start);

                                // handle message
                                string response = HandleMessage(temp);

                                // Send response
                                handler.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // close connection
                    handler.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Terminating - press ENTER");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

 private static string HandleMessage(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message");

            var msg = new Message();
            msg.Parse(data);

            Console.WriteLine("Parsed message     : {0}", msg.MessageType() );
            Console.WriteLine("Message timestamp  : {0}", msg.MessageDateTime() );
            Console.WriteLine("Message control id : {0}", msg.MessageControlId());


            // *********************************************************************
            // Here you could do something usefull with the received message ;-)
            // *********************************************************************


            // todo 


            // Create a response message
            //
            var response = new Message();

            var msh = new Segment("MSH");
            msh.Field(2, "^~\\&");
            msh.Field(7, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz"));
            msh.Field(9, "ACK");
            msh.Field(10, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() );
            msh.Field(11, "P");
            msh.Field(12, "2.5.1");
            response.Add(msh);

            var msa = new Segment("MSA");
            msa.Field(1, "AA");
            msa.Field(2, msg.MessageControlId());
            response.Add(msa);


            // Put response message into an MLLP frame ( <VT> data <FS><CR> )
            //
            var frame = new StringBuilder();
            frame.Append((char) 0x0B);
            frame.Append(response.Serialize());
            frame.Append( (char) 0x1C);
            frame.Append( (char) 0x0D);

            return frame.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but I am getting following error:

> **SocketException was caught :- An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

Please give me any solution.

Comment: on which line and where do you get the exception, client or server ?

Comment: i have write comment error line code and this code for server

Comment: Your utf8 decoding will fail if a read boundary falls in the middle of a codepoint.

Comment: Tell us the value of `endPoint.ToString()`.

Comment: endpoint = 127.0.0.1:8567;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception message tells that you don't have access rights to the socket you created. This can be caused by either socket being already used or user running this process having lower rights than necessary (non-admin rights; this is less likely the reason of the exception in your case).

To check whether some process is already using the socket, open Command Prompt and execute:

```
netstat -o | find "8567"
```

Comment: I checked                                                                                             netstat -o | find "8567" command , i saw 8567 port is not show in list.

Comment: Do you have any local firewall or antivirus software running? Have you tried  using another port number? Or running the app with Admin rights?